# A numerical sequence in Qgis attribute table

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, fields-attributes

In my attribute table of a shapefile I created a new field ('number') and I would like to fill it with:

[image]

Comment: and your question is?

Comment: How can I create the sequence "1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 ..." in a new field?

Comment: `ceil("id" / 3)`

Comment: I would like to have 3 times "1", than 3 times "2", than 3 times "3" and so on...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you create your new field do it like this:

[image: Field calculator]

The formula `floor(("id" + 2) / 3)` (or more simply as **Kazuhito** suggests `ceil("id" / 3)`) results in the pattern you are looking for:

[image: Resulting attribute values]

Comment: @Quarantäne if the answer resolved your question please accept it as correct. This is done with the tick mark next to the voting buttons.